# Can you upload a document template to a subfolder without it showing as a template the main library or other subfolders?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, subfolders

I have set up main Document libraries for different roles within our organization i.e. support staff, supervisors, clinicians.  Within those libraries I have created folders for different types of services and assigned different access/permissions.

Each of these types of services have specific documents which need to be completed. I have Word Templates that staff can fill in quickly.  I would like to upload them as templates but only have them show as a template in a specific Subfolder in a document library. When I upload to create a template it shows in the every folder as a template.

I tried to just add the Word template documents to the folder.  So staff could click on them and fill the information in.  But when they click on the form it opens the actual Document (not a copy i.e. document1) and I'm concerned that they will forget to save as and actually edit the master document.   The staff I work with are not always very computer savvy and choose not to be, so the simpler the better.

Is there a way for it to only show as a template in a specific subfolder?  OR for a way to put a Word Document Template in the folder and have it come up as a new document when selected?

I'm rather new to Sharepoint but am charged with creating one SharePoint site for a program with 3 different locations and 2 types of services.  All with HIPAA needs.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, you have to create a document library for each service with your prefer template

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **No**.

Document templates works with [Content Types](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-multiple-office-templates-to-a-document-library-cde94e90-a1ba-4b94-a187-600ed68562bb) (or [File Types](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/set-a-custom-template-for-a-sharepoint-library-8e0177eb-46bd-4346-9998-330c32733c25) when multiple content types is not enabled). They work on library level and cannot be restrict to subfolders.